# Subset based on column names containing certain words

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset columns containing the word "disagreement" but maintain the first three columns containing ID information. How can I adapt the code below to keep the ID columns?

```
df.disagreement <- df[ , grepl("disagreement", names( df ) )]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the situation that `select()` from `dplyr` was born for:

```
library(dplyr)
select(df, 1:3, contains("disagreement"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you mean:
`df.disagreement <- df[ , c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, grepl("disagreement", names( df )[-c(1:3)] ))]`?

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks! (after I added one ")":
    df.disagreement <- df[ , c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, grepl("disagreement_ratio", names( df )[-c(1:3)] ))]

Answer (score 1):

```
df.disagreement <- df[ , names(df) %in% c("index1", "index2", "index3") | 
                         grepl("disagreement", names( df ) )]
```

OR

```
df.disagreement <- df[ , names(df) %in% names(df)[1:3] | 
                         grepl("disagreement", names( df ) )]
```

Maybe an explanation would be valuable too... So, your grepl statement makes a vector of TRUE / FALSE with the length as the number of names in df. So, the solution above uses that TRUE / FALSE vector and uses a logical OR (|) with another TRUE / FALSE vector (names(df) %in% something). You can do this with another statement too, just add another | or & and keep rollin'.